# AngularJS $watch a div element property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I need to react on a div property change (`element.getBoundingClientRect().left`), so I'm `$scope.$watch()`'ing it. This element is wrapped by a scrollable holder.

It kinda works, but the watcher only triggers as long as the holder is not scrollable. I can tell the clientRect is updated by checking the element prop manually.

An example can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/Darksoulsong/pen/yXYJpZ?editors=0010). Keep adding boxes until the scroll shows up. Note that `box1ClientRectLeft` ceases to update. Click the refresh button and you'll see that the value changes as expected. Remove the boxes until the scroll disappears and se the watcher working again. How can I fix this?

**Note: it must be done without the use of DOM events like on scroll and so on.**

The code:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('boxesController', controller);

function controller ($scope) {  
  $scope.boxes = [
    { name: 1 }
  ];

  $scope.add = function () {
    $scope.boxes.push({name: $scope.boxes.length + 1});
  };

  $scope.remove = function () {
    $scope.boxes.pop();
  };

  $scope.refreshClientRect = function () {
    $scope.box1ClientRectLeft = document.querySelectorAll('#box-1')[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
  }

  $scope.$watch(() => document.querySelectorAll('#box-1')[0].getBoundingClientRect().left, (val) => {
    $scope.box1ClientRectLeft = val;
  });

}
```

Comment: please dont use the angular tag for angularjs related questions

Comment: why are you trying to watch the DOM?  This is counter to everything that angular is designed to accomplish.

Comment: also, what you are describing as a "bug" doesn't really seem to be a bug;  there is no `ClientRect` if the object is not drawn on the page.  if you scroll until the new object would even partially appear, the value updates correctly, as the new object actually is drawn.

Comment: I'm not trying to report a bug, sorry if looked that way. I'm watching a DOM el because I need to do DOM interactions that aren't triggered directly by the user. 

These boxes are added dynamically and I need to draw other elements in the screen and run other operations right after that. An animation occurs, so I need to wait the animation to finish, too much overkill to a simple thing, so its easier to watch the box position and act according to it.

Comment: if there is not ClientRect, why the value is updated when I click the refresh button?